# Exclude max element from each row

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I wrote sql

```
select array_agg(id) as ids
from fff
group by a_c_id, a_c_dttm, a_c_code
having COUNT(*)>1
```

which returns results

```
{5,9}
{8,12,13}
{6,10}
{7,11}
```

How to exclude max value in each row for getting this result?

```
{5}
{8,12}
{6}
{7}
```

the end goal is to get the following result: `{5,8,12,6,7}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate in one table all `ids` except max in groups:

```sql
select array_agg(id) as ids
from my_table
where id not in (
    select max(id)
    from my_table
    group by other_col
);
```

Note that one-element groups are also excluded, so you do not have to treat them separately.

Test it in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/5ViueRxN)

Answer (score 1):

Use the max window function to filter out max id values for each group, so you may modify your query as the following:

```
select array_agg(id) as ids
from 
(
  select *,
    max(id) over (partition by a_c_id, a_c_dttm, a_c_code) maxid
  from table_name
) t
where id <> maxid
group by a_c_id, a_c_dttm, a_c_code
```

Here, you don't need the `having COUNT(*)>1` since one value (max value) is filtered out so the returned groups contain more than one row.

And to get all of the ids aggregated in a single row just remove the group by clause.

[see demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/HLxd5_p0)

Answer (score 0):

```
select array_agg(id) as ids
from fff
WHERE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a_c_id, a_c_dttm, a_c_code ORDER BY ID DESC) <> 1 
group by a_c_id, a_c_dttm, a_c_code
having COUNT(*) =>1
```

You may need to move the ROW_NUMBER to a sub-query, some platforms don't allow it in the WHERE statement.